# The proof that a polynomial has at most as many distinct zeros as its degree in Axler's Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

In Axler's book, the proof is done by an induction on the degree of the polynomial. However, based on the theorem before it (4.11. Each zero of a polynomial corresponds to a degree-1 factor), I think there might be an simpler proof using contradiction, but I'm not sure if I'm right. So I will post my proof here and hopefully someone can judge it for me. Thanks!

Proof: Suppose $p\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ with $m=\deg p$ is a polynomial with more than m distinct zeros. Call them $z_1,\dots,z_n, n>m$. Then by repeated factoring the polynomial into product of degree-1 factors (Using Theorem 4.11 of Axler), we have $$p(z)=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdots(z-z_n)q(z)$$

for some $q\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ and all $z\in \mathbb{F}$. However, the products on the right hand side has degree $\geq n>m$, leading to a contradiction.

(Theorem 4.11: Suppose $p\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F}$) and $\lambda\in \mathbb{F}$, then $p(\lambda)=0$ iff there exists $q\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ such that $p(z)=(z-\lambda)q(z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{F}$. )

Comment: They're essentially the same proof. There's a hidden induction when you say "by repeated factoring".

Comment: Why is it always possible to factorize $p$ in degree $1$-factors?

Comment: @Shahab because for all these $n$ roots I can pick the first one $z_1$ and factor it out, then the other roots must be roots of $q=p/(z-z_1)$ and so I can continue to factor the roots out

Comment: @Reveillark Makes sense...maybe mine is not that rigorous...but I find Axler's proof kind of tortuous. I wish to understand why might he choose to do it that way.  Put it more succinctly...what is the motivation for his proof.

Comment: There is no reason to use contradiction in your proof. One can develop the expression for $p$, just as you did, then note that $m = \deg p = n + \deg q$, and since $\deg q > 0$, we have $n \le m$. This is still using induction, which Axler may have chosen to make explicit exactly because few students understand that "repeating" is induction. (As a guess - the only motivation of Axler I am sure of is his dislike of determinants in introductory L.A., for which he is famous.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ah! Thanks for pointing this out. Now I see how my contradiction is superfluous....